# Rolling minimum per row using dates

Tags: r

I have data with the following structure:

```
data.frame(value = c(1, 2, 10), date = as.Date(c('2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-04')))
```

and I want to compute the rolling minimum of value per row with a window of the last two days. That is, the output of this computation should be

```
data.frame(value = c(1, 2, 10), date = as.Date(c('2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-04')),
       minimum = c(1, 1, 10))
```

Is there an easy way to do this using the tidyverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could go for:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(
    minimum = sapply(date, function(x) min(value[between(date, x - 1, x)]))
  )
```

Output:

```
  value       date minimum
1     1 2018-01-01       1
2     2 2018-01-02       1
3    10 2018-01-04      10
```